# Can the __name__ attribute be accessed from an imported module

Tags: python, import, module, attributes

Given a module A, which imports a module B, is there a way for a function in module B (used in module A) to access the `__name__` attribute from module A without it being passed explicitly (as, for example, a function argument)?

Comment: Only if it has a reference to `A` in the first place, which I don't believe is implicitly available due to the fact that Python is lexically scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by "reaching back" through function call stack one level to get access the calling function's globals stored in the frame's `f_globals` attribute. 
Here's what I mean:

```
# The main script.

import module_A

module_A.func()
```

---

```
# module_A.py

import module_B

def func():
    module_B.func()
```

---

```
# module_B.py

import sys

def func():
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # caller's globals
    print(f'module_B.func() was called from {namespace["__name__"]}')
```

Output from running the main script:

```
module_B.func() was called from module_A
```

I'd like to add that this is kind of a hacky thing to be doing, so you might want to think twice before doing it in production code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're being called from module A, you may be able to work back the stack frame and get the name of the filename of the function that called the B module function from.  Below is some sample code for walking the stack.

```
import inspect

def recurse(limit):
    local_variable = '.' * limit
    if limit <= 0:
        for frame, filename, line_num, func, source_code, source_index in inspect.stack():
            print '%s[%d]\n  -> %s' % (filename, line_num, source_code[source_index].strip())
            print inspect.getargvalues(frame)
            print
        return
    recurse(limit - 1)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recurse(3)
```

Comment: No need to mention it…literally.

Comment: An observation: Effective 2020-01-01, no new bug reports, fixes, or changes will be made to Python 2 ([announcement](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2019/12/python-2-sunset.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+PythonSoftwareFoundationNews+%28Python+Software+Foundation+News%29)), so I suggest you migrate to Python 3.x as soon as possible.